# Force resource at the beginning and end of exection?

Tags: terraform

I currently think about a way to implement a conditional maintenance page during a terraform run.
So thinking about a boolean SSM parameter that, when set to true, leads to a resource that puts a redirect rule into the ALB that serves a static maintenance page.

But I don't know if there is a way to force a terraform resource to be executed at the beginnen (or as soon as possible) and another one in the end of one apply run.

Someone has an idea?

(Sidenote: I know that I could do a separate steps in the pipeline but maybe there is a way to do it in one tf apply.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform has no primitives to build something like this. Terraform's "core mission" is to apply changes to objects to match a given desired state, and although that is sufficient to solve the whole problem in some cases, for some use-cases it's better to think of Terraform as just a building block.

Generally I'd suggest to do it as part of a broader automation system of which Terraform is a part, so that you can decide for yourself how to handle situations such as when the Terraform apply fails for some reason, or situations where a particular plan could be applied *without* the downtime.

For the former: you'll need to decide whether an apply failure causes the downtime flag to remain set or whether it optimistically unsets it to try to bring things back up. What is right for you will depend on the specifics of your situation.

For the latter: in normal Terraform usage, once your infrastructure is set up you're hopefully only applying small in-place updates to it where possible, so it's possible that some operations will not require downtime. If that applies to you, you could consider generating a saved plan (`terraform plan -out=tfplan`) and then reading the resulting plan as JSON (`terraform show -json tfplan`) to feed into a custom program that decides whether the described actions are "safe" or not, so it can decide whether downtime is required and thus whether to set the "downtime" flag.

The HashiCorp Learn site has a guide [Running Terraform in Automation](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/development/running-terraform-in-automation) that covers some recommendations and considerations for using Terraform as part of a broader automation system.